# Counting in Logo

Tags: turtle-graphics

I wish to write a simple procedure in the Logo programming language (Turtle), which does this process a number of times (the number of times can be an input of the procedure): generate a random number between 0 to 10. If the number is below 5, make the turtle red, if above/equal make it blue. In addition, I want to count the number of times the turtle was blue and to return the probability of a blue turtle.

My problem is mainly in assigning values to variables. I don't know how to create a counting variable in Logo and couldn't find it anywhere online. The part of counter = counter + 1, how do I do that in Logo?

Any help with this simple friendly procedure will be most appreciated ! :-)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to create a counting variable in Logo and couldn't
>   find it anywhere online. The part of counter = counter + 1, how do I
>   do that in Logo?

A common approach involves [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)):

```
to count :counter
  if :counter = 0 [STOP]
  pr :counter
  count :counter - 1
end

count 10
```

If you want to decrement (or increment) the counter directly, you can instead do:

```
to count :counter
  if :counter = 0 [STOP]
  pr :counter
  make "counter :counter - 1
  count :counter
end

count 10
```

I'm guessing Logo relies on [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) to optimize this approach to be as efficient as iteration.